# Python 3: Cant search for dictionary keys with more than 1 character

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am extremely new to Python and have only just started learning so any advice and tips would be fantastic.
Im trying to make a program that allows the user to convert text into Binary.

The process for this would be Text > Hexidecimal > Binary.

Im doing this mainly to challenge myself and to get a better understanding of how Python works, so excuse the terrible code.

The issue im facing is that when the user inputs a Hexidecimal such as "41" the program should check the dictionary for the associated value, which would be "01000001". But instead i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Kye\Desktop\Python\Word Encrypter.py\Word Encryption.py", line 48, in <module>
print(to_bin_code())
File "c:\Users\Kye\Desktop\Python\Word Encrypter.py\Word Encryption.py", line 44, in to_bin_code
bin_code = bin_code + hex_to_bin_dic[user_text]
KeyError: '2'
```

For now the the program is set up to give the user an option of using either the Hexidecimal converter which does text to hex, or the Binary converter which is supposed to turn hex into binary.

```
def to_bin_code():
    hex_to_bin_dic = {
        "A": "01000001", "42": "01000010", "CC": "01000011", "4": "01000100",
    }

    bin_code = ""

    for user_text in text:
        bin_code = bin_code + hex_to_bin_dic[user_text]
    return bin_code

text=input("Type or Paste you Hexidecimal code here for conversion: \n")
print(to_bin_code())

to_bin_code()
```

This is the block thats suppossed to turn hex into binary. The keys in place at the moment are just to show the issue im having, the only key that will be staying is "42". But if you run the program keys "A" and "4" work but keys "42" and "CC" dont work.

Heres the full code. Also i know a lot can be abbreviated but i want it in the most basic form for now so i can understand it better:

```
print("Would you like to do a Hexidecimal Conversion or Binary Conversion? ")

hex_or_bin = input()

if hex_or_bin == ("Hex" or "Hexidecimal"):
    def to_hex_code():
        word_to_hex_dic = {
            "A": "41", "B": "42", "C": "43", "D": "44", "E": "45",
            "F": "46", "G": "47", "H": "48", "I": "49", "J": "4A", "K": "4B", "L": "4C", "M": "4D", "N": "4E",
            "O": "4F", "P": "50", "Q": "51", "R": "52", "S": "53", "T": "54", "U": "55", "V": "56", "W": "57",
            "X": "58", "Y": "59", "Z": "5A", "a": "61", "b": "62", "c": "63", "d": "64", "e": "65", "f": "66",
            "g": "67", "h": "68", "i": "69", "j": "6A", "k": "6B", "l": "6C", "m": "6D", "n": "6E", "o": "6F",
            "p": "70", "q": "71", "r": "72", "s": "73", "t": "74", "u": "75", "v": "76", "w": "77", "x": "78",
            "y": "79", "z": "7A", " ": "20", "!": "21", "\"": "22", "#": "23", "$": "24", "%": "25", "&": "26",
            "'": "27", "(": "28", ")": "29", "*": "2A", "+": "2B", ",": "2C", "-": "2D", ".": "2E", "/": "2F",
            ":": "3A", ";": "3B", "<": "3C", "=": "3D", ">": "3E", "?": "3F", "@": "30", "[": "5B", "\\": "5C",
            "]": "5D", "^": "5E", "_": "5F", "`": "60", "{": "7B", "|": "7C", "}": "7D", "~": "7E", "0": "30",
            "1": "31", "2": "32", "3": "33", "4": "34", "5": "35", "6": "36", "7": "37", "8": "38", "9": "39",
}

#       hex_to_word_dic = {value: key for key,value in word_to_hex_dic.items()}

        hex_code = ""

        for user_text in text:
            hex_code = hex_code + word_to_hex_dic[user_text]
        return hex_code

    text=input("Type or Paste you message here for Hexidecimal conversion: \n")
    print(to_hex_code())

    to_hex_code()

elif hex_or_bin == ("Bin" or "Binary"):
    def to_bin_code():
        hex_to_bin_dic = {
            "A": "01000001", "42": "01000010", "CC": "01000011", "4": "01000100",
        }

        bin_code = ""

        for user_text in text:
            bin_code = bin_code + hex_to_bin_dic[user_text]
        return bin_code

    text=input("Type or Paste you Hexidecimal code here for conversion: \n")
    print(to_bin_code())

    to_bin_code()

else:
    print("Thankyou for using this converter")
```

Comment: `for user_text in text` will iterate through your input, one character at a time.

Comment: fwiw, you might be interested in `int(..., 16)` (parse string as hex), `hex(...)` (convert integer to hex string), `bin(...)` (convert integer to string) and/r the `:b` / `:x` string formatting specifiers (binary and hex respectively)

Comment: You might want to dumb it down a little, just started learning Python so theres a lot i dont know yet. What does this do specifically? and how will it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) lookup table instead. Change your dict to:

```
hex_to_bin_dic = {
    "0": "0000", "1": "0001", "2": "0010", "3": "0011", 
    "4": "0100", "5": "0101", "6": "0110", "7": "0111", 
    "8": "1000", "9": "1001", "A": "1010", "B": "1011", 
    "C": "1100", "D": "1101", "E": "1110", "F": "1111"
    }
```